# Please identify my mistake: $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln (1+2 h)-2 \ln (1+h)}{h^2}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Anyone please tell what mistake I am making?

$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h \to 0} & \frac{\ln (1+2 h)-2 \ln (1+h)}{h^2} \\
& =\frac{4 \ln (1+2 h)}{4 h^2}-\frac{2 \ln (1+h)}{h^2} \\
& =\frac{4 \ln (1+2 h)}{(2 h)(2 h)}-\frac{2\ln (1+h)}{(h)(h)} \\
& =\frac{4}{2 h}-\frac{2}{h} \\
& =0
\end{aligned}$

I want to know why I am getting zero.

Comment: Can't just cancel like that. Try the taylor series of $\ln(1+u)$.

Comment: You cannot take limits in pieces like you did i.e. you cannot say $f(h)g(2h) - k(h)g(h) \to f(h)g(0) - k(h)g(0)$. When you take a limit and it was not completely factorable before the limit, you need to take all of the $h$s to zero, not just some of them.

Comment: It is not clear how you jumped from the second to third equality.

Comment: $\( \operatorname{Lim}_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln (1+h)}{h}=1 \)$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think @ninad munshi comment is correct. Can any support his comment

Comment: The separate limits do not exist, so you can't use the limit in the comment above.

Comment: Factorisation gives $\dfrac2h\left[\dfrac{\ln(1+2h)}{2h} - \dfrac{\ln(1+h)}{h}\right]$, an $\infty\cdot 0$ indeterminate form which may have non-zero limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \ln(1+2h) - 2 \ln(1+h)}{h^2}$ means the limit of the expression inside as $h$ is a real number tending to $0.$ The scope of definition of $h$ is restricted to the expression of the limit. However, the expression in the second line $\frac{4 \ln(1+2h)}{4h^2}$ has no meaning because $h$ has no declared meaning here.

Next, the addition rule of limits states that the limit of sum of two expressions is the sum of the limits of two expressions *provided both exist and are well defined*. In the case you are considering, neither $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{4\ln(1+2h)}{4h^2}$ nor $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2 \ln(1+h)}{h^2}$ is defined as a real number.

Finally, even if the limits both exist and are equal to $+\infty,$ you appear to be computing $+\infty-\infty=0$ which is invalid because the operation of addition is defined on pairs of real numbers and infinity is not a real (or complex) number.

Answer (score 2):

As has been said, you are taking the limit in some parts of the expression only, then simplifying to take another limit later: won't work.

However this can be fixed. Here you have replaced parts of the expression with approximations. It's correct **if** you take the rest into account.

That is, you are allowed to write $\log(1+2h)=2h+O(h^2)$, therefore $\dfrac{\log(1+2h)}{h^2}=\dfrac{2h+O(h^2)}{h^2}$, then likewise $\log(1+h)=h+O(h^2)$ therefore $2\dfrac{\log(1+h)}{h^2}=\dfrac{2h+O(h^2)}{h^2}$.

And then the difference is

$$\frac{\log(1+2h)}{h^2}-\frac{2\log(1+h)}{h^2}=\frac{2h+O(h^2)-2h-O(h^2)}{h^2}=\frac{O(h^2)}{h^2}=O(1)$$

That is, all you can conclude is the LHS is bounded. Note the $O(h^2)$ don't cancel, all you can say is $O(h^2)-O(h^2)=O(h^2)$. Think of $O(h^2)$ as *"an unknown function $f$ such that $f(h)=g(h)h^2$, with bounded $g$"*, and each time you are using such an approximation, you have to assume it's another such unknown function.

To find the limit, take the approximation an order further: $\frac{log(1+2h)}{h^2}=2h-2h^2+O(h^3)$ and $2\log(1+h)=2h-h^2+O(h^3)$, then

$$\frac{\log(1+2h)}{h^2}-2\frac{\log(1+h)}{h^2}=\frac{2h-2h^2+O(h^3)-2h+h^2+O(h^3)}{h^2}=\frac{-h^2+O(h^3)}{h^2}=-1+O(h)$$

And the limit is $-1$.

Comment: @Dharnesh It's just Taylor expansion with big-O rest. In french they are called *développements limités*. The great advantage is you can apply operations on them, including function composition, and still get an accurate approximation.

Comment: Thank you i understood